# Function queue based on time

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want implement function queue,where it should be executed based upon passed in time delay. If any of the function in the queue is invoked before the delay, then queue must not execute that function and should be moved to the next function in the queue.

For example:

```
function funQueue(message,date){

  //logic
}

var fn1=funQueue("message1",new Date().getTime()+500)
var fn2=funQueue("message2",new Date().getTime()+1000)
var fn3=funQueue("message3",new Date().getTime()+2000)
    fn2()
```

When it is executed like the above it should print.

**message1**

**message3**

please note **message2** is not printed.

Thanks all,

Comment: Please tell us why `var fn2` is not executed? You can't tell if this function will ever be called again

Comment: @Justinas - it is executed ... see `fn2()` - that executes it

Comment: But `fn1` and `fn3` is not called again. You do not assign function, you assign value of function return. So what is the logic?

Comment: @Justinas funQueue return a handler to cancel the execution

Comment: You say "queue", but the functions aren't really queued up after each other, are they? They each have an independently specified run time that could be in any order? You don't want `funQueue()` to take a function as an argument, and execute *that* function after the specified delay? (You just want it to display a string message?)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little something like the following, using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout):

```js
function funQueue(message,date){
  var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {  // schedule a timeout
    console.log(message)                   // that logs the message
  }, date - new Date().getTime())          // at the specified time
  
  return function() {                      // return a function
    clearTimeout(timeoutId)                // that cancels the timeout
  }
}

var fn1=funQueue("message1",new Date().getTime()+500)
var fn2=funQueue("message2",new Date().getTime()+1000)
var fn3=funQueue("message3",new Date().getTime()+2000)
fn2()
```

Note that if you call `funQueue()` with a time that is in the past it will still call `setTimeout()`, which means the message would be logged immediately after the current code completes unless it is cancelled within the current code.

**EDIT:** I was asked in a comment to implement it without multiple simultaneous timeouts. The following is the first way that came to mind. I'm sure this could be tidied up, optimised, and/or completely rewritten in a better way, but it worked the first time I clicked "run" so I think it's a good enough starting place. I'll leave the explanation of how it works as an exercise for the reader...

```js
var funQueue = function() {
  var queue = []
  var timeoutId
  function setNext() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    if (queue.length > 0) {
      timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(queue.shift().message)
        setNext()
      }, queue[0].date - new Date().getTime())
    }
  }  
  return function(message,date){
    var item = { message: message, date: date }
    var i = 0
    while (i < queue.length && date >= queue[i].date) i++
    queue.splice(i, 0, item)
    setNext()
    return function() {  
      var i = queue.indexOf(item)
      if (i != -1) {
        queue.splice(i, 1)
        setNext()
      }
    }
  }
}()

var fn1=funQueue("message1",new Date().getTime()+500)
var fn2=funQueue("message2",new Date().getTime()+1000)
var fn3=funQueue("message3",new Date().getTime()+2000)
var fn4=funQueue("message4",new Date().getTime()+1500)
var fn5=funQueue("message5",new Date().getTime()+2000)
fn2()
```

Comment: Nice. I think here setTimeout creates multiple instances of it, can we do it in way that we can have only one instance of setTimeout

Comment: Calling `setTimeout()` schedules a *single* timeout. You need one timeout per message, because each message has its own delay and needs to be independently cancellable. Click the "Run code snippet" button and see the result for yourself.

Comment: I mean, if I call funQueue three times,then 3 timers will be started right?

Comment: Yes. But as I said, you *need* that because each call to `funQueue()` specifies its own time. I'm not sure how else you think it could work.

Comment: can we have one timer to pickup these messages. something like storing all string messages in one array and letting  timer to pickup the string message that should fire next.

Comment: Yes. But I wouldn't recommend it, the code would be more complicated because when you add a string to the array you'd have to check if it should be printed before the currently scheduled string and if so cancel that, etc.. In my opinion what I've shown is the best option - why are you concerned about only having one timer?

Comment: You could use a single `setInterval()` to check every *n* milliseconds whether it is time to display any messages, but then that code would be continuously executing over and over (many thousands of times) even if you only ever queued a couple of messages.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but my functional requirement needs only one timer even if it is complex. Could you please guide me on this :)

Comment: If you mean literally one call to `setTimeout()` that's not possible. If you mean multiple calls to `setTimeout()` but only ever one at a time (with the next after the previous was completed or cancelled) that could be done. Or one call to `setInterval()` could also work as already mentioned but I don't like that option. Either way would make the returned cancel handler code way more complicated than it is in my current answer.

Comment: this fine,  multiple calls to setTimeout() but only ever one at a time (with the next after the previous was completed or cancelled)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this to check whether the time has passed or not

```
var timePassed;
function funQueue(message, date){
  if(timePassed > date){
     timePassed = new Date.getTime();
     // Do stuff
  }
}
```